# I am unable to start my Kali Linux

Tags: apt, kali-linux

I did 'apt-get dist upgrade' and upgraded it. It was done 100% but it asked me to open the upgraded packages so I did yes and I went out for a work for 1 hour. But after I came I saw that my pc was on standby mode. So I pressed some keys but it didn't start so I restarted my pc and I started Kali bit after inserting username and password it gave a white screen and when I tried to open terminal it opens and after a second it again took me to inserting username and password point.

Comment: You are logging in as root or non-root? If non-root then maybe ownership error of `.Xauthority` file.

Comment: Please give me an answer. Don't tell me that who all have asked the same question

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Start your kali in cli mode and type `apt-get autoremove` and hit enter. This will work most of time.